# Joining data with Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, join, union

I'm trying to retrieve all employments linked to employees with a given UserID + all employments linked to managers with a given UserID. I'm joining the sets of data the way SQL UNION would do. This is the code I wrote for this purpose, but it seems that INCLUDEs are cumulative (the second works on the set of data retrieved by the first), which is not my intention (the second set of data has to add to the first):

```
var list = await db.Employment.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.Active)
    .Include(x => x.Employee).Where(x => x.Employee.UserID == UserID)
    .Include(x => x.Manager).Where(x => x.Manager.UserID == UserID)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Employment model

```
public class Employment : IHasID, IValidatableObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int? ManagerID { get; set; }
    public Employee Manager { get; set; }
}
```

Employee model

```
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? UserID { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Employee")]
    public List<Employment> EmploymentEmployee { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Manager")]
    public List<Employment> EmploymentManager { get; set; }
}
```

Later, I discovered that there's a Union extension, so I tried to use it:

```
var list = await
db.Employment.Where(x => x.Active).Include(x => x.Employee)
.Include(x => x.Manager).Where(x => x.Employee.UserID == UserID)
.Union(
db.Employment.Where(x => x.Active).Include(x => x.Employee)
.Include(x => x.Manager).Where(x => x.Manager.UserID == UserID))
.ToListAsync();
```

...but this results in an exception: InvalidOperationException: Warning as error exception for warning 'CoreEventId.IncludeIgnoredWarning': The Include operation for navigation: 'x.Employee' was ignored because the target navigation is not reachable in the final query results.

Comment: Your description is not clear, too many ambiguous words ("cumulative" vs. "add"). Show sample data of what you get and what you want.

Comment: You misunderstood the purpose of `Include` method and what it does. I think you are seeking for single `Where` like `x => x.Employee.UserID == UserID || x.Manager.UserID == UserID`

Comment: @Ivan - yes, with the difference that when both of the OR conditions are satisfied I want to have 2 records (entities) in the result set.